# Background image in id selector not showing up

Tags: html, css, background, selector

I cannot get this background image to appear. It is supposed to appear in the background with the header overlapping it. I'm using an id selector. I literally copied this straight from the book i have for my class and it's not working at all.

Here is my code. I'm very new to css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Fall Nature Hikes</title>
<style>
#content { background-image: url(fall.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 640px;
height: 480px;
padding-top: 20px; } 

h1 { background-color: #FFFFFF;
opacity: 0.6;
font-size: 4em;
padding: 10 px; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1>Fall Nature Hikes</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: background-image: ("fall.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

In my browser it works right for another image, you can check the url(fall.jpg) path is right？

Answer (score 0):

I checked, your code can show the image, you can see this sample:

```
> https://jsfiddle.net/a9qm1j2t/
```

It's just copy all your html and css source code.

I think you should check image path and image type again, and make sure it's right.

Answer (score 0):

May be your image path is not proper. 
First check where is your css file and image file.You can verify your image path by inspecting your code on browser and in style check your image path.